# Wierd output from vsprintf

Tags: php, printf

I am trying to build a data-file with hardcoded strings...

So I am using this format:

```
Format: %a1s%06c%a20s%a30s%a30s%a30s%a30s%a7s%a13s%a20s%a8s%a1s%a1s%a1s%a30s%a14s%a1s%a2s%a39s%a8s%a30s%a2s%a13s%a5s%a7s%a1s%a8s%03c
Values:     "A",    "16",   "",     "",     "Ola Nordmann",     "Slottsgate 1",     "",     "1012",     "",     "",     "",     "",     "",     "P",    "",     "",     "I",    "",     "",     "",     "",     "",     "",     "",     "",     "",     "",     ""

Output: "1s20s30s30s30s30s7s13s20s8s1s1s1s30s14s1s2s39s8s30s2s13s5s7s1s8s"
```

My code:

```
    $aRecord = vsprintf($format, $values);
    return ['a-record' => $aRecord, 'values' => $values, 'format' => $format];
```

Probably just beacuse its pretty late and friday afternoon, hope some of you guys will se my mistake... Thanks! :)

EDIT:

Expected output:

```
A000016                                                  Ola Nordmann            Slottsgate 1                                                1012
```

Comment: and what's going wrong with this ?

Comment: @HalayemAnis Thanks for asking! I added my expected output too the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution whas pretty simple :P

For left-aligning text, we need to use `-` instead of `a`

```
printf("% -20s", "Richard");
```

Hope this helps someone :)